# Transient Response, State Response, and Zero-Input/Zero-State, Natural and Forced

Tags: circuit-analysis, calculus

I would just like to know if each of these "responses" are the same. Are the words being used just synonyms of each other?

- Steady State and Transient
- Natural and Forced
- Zero-Input and Zero-State

These are in no particular order whatsoever, but I see a connection among these terms and would like to know it. Thank you

Comment: Can you explain the connections that you see? Which terms do you think might be synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

The steady-state response is not the Transient or Zero-input or Zero-state or Natural or Forced response: All of those other words refer to the **initial** conditions and state: the *steady-state* response is what happens after the initial conditions and state no longer apply.

Zero-input (natural) and Zero-state (Forced) are the two components of Transient response.

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to go through an example. Consider the simple RC circuit below: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK38Ge.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switch has been open for a very long time, so \$V_C(0) = 0\text{V} \$. Closing the switch and writing up a differential equation for \$V_C(t) \$ gives you
$$\dot{V_C(t)} +\frac{1}{RC}V_C(t)=\frac{1}{RC}V_s$$

The solution to the differential equation has two components. A natural response (homogeneous solution) and a forced response (particular solution).

First, we find the **forced response** by finding a particular solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation. This is usually done with a guess, and we see that \$V_C(t) = V_s \$ satisfies the differential equation. Due to the existence and uniqueness theorem, we conclude \$ x_0=V_s\$ where \$x_0 \$ denotes the particular solution.

Secondly, we find the **natural response** by zeroing the right hand side and solving for \$V_C(t) \$.

$$\dot{V_C(t)} +\frac{1}{RC}V_C(t) = 0 \: \Rightarrow V_{C,hom}(t) = K_1e^{-\frac{t}{RC}} $$

Now we have the total response: -
$$V_{C,total}(t)=x_0+V_{C,hom}(t) = \underbrace{V_s}_{\text{Steady-state}}+\underbrace{K_1e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}}_{\text{Transient}} $$
As I have denoted, the total solution consists of two components. The right term is the **transient** response, which eventually decays to negligible values. The left term is the **steady state** component persists forever, even after the transient has decayed. I have to be careful with what I say here, but I believe one could say that the transient refers to the system's dynamic response - while steady state refers to the system's static response.

The method I've shown above was the classical method of solving differential equations. However, this method is practically useless since we sometimes deal with systems where we need to know \$V_C(0+) \$ and \$\dot{V_C(0+)} \$ that is, the initial conditions for both the state and the rate of change of the state. Luckily, there is another way of solving linear differential equations - namely by splitting the components into the **zero-state response** and **zero-input response**.

$$y_{total} = y_{zs} + y_{zi} $$ where \$y \$ denotes the response. This is very useful, because we now can use the initial conditions \$V_C(0-) \$ and \$\dot{V_C(0-)} \$ which are possible (and easier) to find than the cases for \$0+ \$.

Either method will give you the same total response. This is illustrated in Lathi 2006: -

[image]